# how to cannot install alien ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

i have rpm package(ex: sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm), but i cannot use 'alien' from software center ubuntu when is i try install 'alien', i have a bug:

> root@temo:~# sudo apt-get -f install alien

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
alien : Depends: debhelper (>= 7) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: rpm (>= 2.4.4-2) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: rpm2cpio
 skype:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libxv1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libpulse0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Plz help in installing alien.

Comment: First Ubuntu doesn't use `rpm` packages, and did you run `sudo apt-get -f install` as suggested by `apt`?

Comment: using `-f` does not help

Answer (score 2):

`alien` often produces unsolvable dependencies in the package being installed due to differences in the naming of libraries in the Debian and Red Hat operating systems, however in Ubuntu 16.04 and all supported versions of Ubuntu it is possible to build a Debian package of Oracle SQL Developer using *sqldeveloper-package* from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install sqldeveloper-package
```

This utility will require you to download the architecture independent archive from `http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer`, identified as "Oracle SQL Developer for other platforms", "Oracle SQL Developer for Multiple Platforms" or "Oracle SQL Developer for Linux and Unix" (depending on which version you  are building), to create the Debian package from.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining that the `alien` package needs (depends on):

```
debhelper version 7 or later (version 9.20160115ubuntu3 is in the repositoires)
rpm version 2.4.4-2 or later (version 4.12.0.1+dfsg1-3build3 is in tyhe repositories)  
rpm2cpio no version specified (version 4.12.0.1+dfsg1-3build3 ...)
```

Read `man apt-get`, you may be able to use `--install-suggests` or `-o APT::Install-Recommends=1` to `apt-get`.